# WPF Web application: How to embed in ASP.NET page?

Tags: wpf, xaml, web-applications

I am trying to bulid a WPF web application.I have 2 projects in the solution .One is of type WPF web application and another is of type ASP.NET web application where i need to embed the WPF stuff.The XAML file runs file when i set startup project as the WPF web app project.How can i add/embed this into the Default.aspx of my ASP.NET Web app project ?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating what is known as a XBAP (XAML Browser Application).

Follow these deployment instructions from MSDN:

[WPF XAML Browser Applications Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx#deploying_a_xbap)